# Where does Kuhn talks about the five characteristics for the choice of theory?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, kuhn

> Kuhn (1977, 321–2) identifies five characteristics that provide the
>   shared basis for a choice of theory: 1. accuracy; 2. consistency (both
>   internal and with other relevant currently accepted theories); 3.
>   scope (its consequences should extend beyond the data it is required
>   to explain); 4. simplicity (organizing otherwise confused and isolated
>   phenomena); 5. fruitfulness (for further research).

(Source: Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy)

I suppose that (1977) is referred to some essay contained in Kuhn's *The essential tension*. For I don't have this book, I cannot check which essay are pages 321-2 referred to.

Where does Kuhn talks about the five characteristics in the quote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The essay is :

> "Objectivity, Value Judgment, and Theory Choice”, in [The Essential Tension](https://books.google.it/books?id=xvRJCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA320), University of Chicago Press (1977), page 320–on. Previously unpublished; lecure delivered at Furman
> University, 30 November 1973.

See page 321-322:

> What, I ask to begin with, are the characteristics of a good scientific theory? Among a number of quite usual answers I select five, not because they are exhaustive, but because they are individually important and collectively sufficiently varied to indicate what is at stake.
>
> First, a theory should be accurate [...]
>
> Second, a theory should be consistent [...]
>
> Third, it should have broad scope [...]
>
> Fourth, and closely related, it should be simple [...]
>
> Fifth—a somewhat less standard item, but one of special importance to actual
> scientific decisions—a theory should be fruitful of new research findings [...]

Answer (score 4):

> Kuhn developed his 'no algorithm' argument [for theory choice : GT] most thoroughly in a
>    1977 essay entitled 'Objectivity, Value Judgment, and Theory Choice'.
>    In that essay, **he identifies five criteria that provide 'the shared basis
>    for theory choice', namely accuracy, consistency, scope, simplicity,
>    and fruitfulness** (Kuhn 1977a, p. 321). These five, he says, are 'the
>    standard criteria for evaluating the adequacy of a theory', widely
>    agreed on by mainstream philosophers of science. Kuhn has no quar
>    rel with the standard view that these criteria play a key role in scientific
>    theory choice; indeed, he regards them as partially constitutive of what
>    science is. However, he argues, using examples from the history of
>    science, that the criteria fail to uniquely determine theory choice, for
>    two reasons. Firstly, the criteria are ambiguous — it may be unclear
>    which of two theories is simpler, for example. In some respects
>    Copernicus' theory was simpler than Ptolemy's, Kuhn says, but in
>    others it was not. Secondly, there is the problem of how to appropri
>    ately weight the criteria when they pull in different directions. How
>    should simplicity be traded off against accuracy and scope, for ex
>    ample? Kuhn says that 'no progress' has been made towards solving
>    this problem (Kuhn 1977, 329). (Samir Okasha, 'Theory Choice and Social Choice: Kuhn versus Arrow', Mind, Vol. 120, No. 477 (January 2011), pp. 83-115 : 85.)

It's vital to add that Kuhn has reservations about these criteria : (1) of two theories, one may be simpler than the other in some respects but not in others; and (2) the criteria do not necessarily converge. One theory can score high on one criterion, another high on a different criterion. There is no lexical ordering of criteria by which we can assign greater weight to one criterion rather than another.

**Reference**

Thomas Kuhn, 'Objectivity, Value Judgment, and Theory Choice', The Essential Tension. Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 1977, 320-39.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given you the reference. See a good abstract of the whole subject in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10838-020-09507-5